# Class cannot be cast

Tags: java, sql

I'm writing a page that has me a login user.

In the database I have a table admins:

```
  CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ePrzychodnia`.`admins` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `personalId` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `personalId_UNIQUE` (`personalId` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `password_UNIQUE` (`password` ASC) )
```

Class Admin, which maps the table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "admins")
@XmlRootElement
public class Admin implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 11)
    @Column(name = "personalId")
    private String personalId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
```

ManagedBean JSF:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginMB {

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "ePrzychodnia-ejbPU";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
    private String login;
    private String password;         

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of LoginMB
     */
    public LoginMB() {
    }

   Getters and setters

    public String validate() {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Admin a WHERE a.personalId = :login AND a.password = :password");
        q.setParameter("login", login);
        q.setParameter("password", password);
        try {
            Admin admin = (Admin) q.getSingleResult();
            if (login.equals(admin.getPersonalId()) && password.equals(admin.getPersonalId())) {
                return "success";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Błąd: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return "failed";
    }
}
```

Login page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Logowanie</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Logowanie</h1>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel value="Login"></h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="login" value="#{loginMB.login}" label="Login">
                    <f:validateRequired/>        
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="login" style="color:red" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Password"></h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputSecret id="pass" value="#{loginMB.password}" label="Password">
                    <f:validateRequired/>        
                </h:inputSecret>
                <h:message for="pass" style="color:red" />
                <h:commandButton value="Logowanie" action="#{loginMB.validate()}"></h:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The table in the database I added the following entry:

```
 INSERT INTO admins VALUES(1, 'admin', 'admin', '12345678901', 'admin');
```

I log on the website login: 12345678901 pass: admin
but I get an error `pl.ePrzychodnia.model.Admin cannot be cast to pl.ePrzychodnia.model.Admin`

Why do I get this error, what did I do wrong?

Stack trace:

```
SEVERE:     at pl.ePrzychodnia.mb.LoginMB.validate(LoginMB.java:57)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
SEVERE:     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
SEVERE:     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
SEVERE:     at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and the relevant method where this error arises.

Comment: Sounds like your classes are being loaded by different class loaders.  A class from one class loader cannot be cast to an object of the same class in another class loader.

Comment: If you haven't yet, try restarting your server and see whether it solves the problem. This could happen if you are redeploying the same application, without restarting the server. In which case, the chance is that a class might get loaded again without being unloaded first in the process of redeploying.

Comment: I added stack trace. Restart does not help

Comment: Thanks Bhesh Gurung. Always the first run everything is ok, but when I redeploying my application i have a this error. I must always restart my server when i redeploy project to avoid this error?

Comment: You said, the restart didn't help right? If it did then - it's not like you must do it, but the problem is that the server is not performing the redeployment process correctly. And in such a scenario that's the only solution AFAIK. Also depending upon the feasibility you might want to consider trying different server (or different version).

Comment: Yes I first said the restart didnt't help. But then I saw that i have error in my code. I have:password.equals(admin.getPersonalId())) and it should be password.equals(admin.getOassword())) I fix it, and the application works. But i still have a problem when i deployed my application i must restart server.